# xfinitywifi keeps getting connected by default (no admin privileges)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, wifi

My work macbook, on which I have no admin privileges, keeps connecting to “xfinitywifi” by default. I want to stop this, but any change in network preferences requires admin privileges.

Is there any other way to turn off auto connecting to a WiFi network?

Comment: Have you contacted your IT department to inform them of the issue?

Comment: @Allan Yes. I'm waiting for a response. In the meantime, I wanted to see if there's another solution that doesn't require admin privileges

Comment: If you’re not an admin, you really can’t get around it.  Plus, if you could bypass admin restrictions, we wouldn’t be doing you any favors with your IT department/employer by circumventing their policies

Answer (score 1):

[image]

***If*** they left you the ability to **Turn WiFi on or off** without admin privileges (while requiring them for *Changing Networks*) you could use that.

If they didn't, you're stuck waiting for them, or them actually wanting it that way and refusing to change it.